# ionic 1 splash screen with multiple images

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I am trying add 2 or more images in my splash screen on specific locations, like 1 image is my Logo which will be center of screen and Other image is pattern design which will be on the bottom of screen with full width, and the Background will be a solid color. I have googled but I am only getting general `config.xml` file style. like below:

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon qualifier="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
```

is there any proper way to get it done?

Answer (score 0):

Splash screens are largely non programmable, and does not support even pretty basic stuff like localization. One possible workaround for your issue is to add HTML for your "splash screen" in the `index.html` file, inside the `<ion-app>` tags.

```
<ion-app>
 <div class="appload">
  <div class="loadingtext">
    <div class="primary-text">

    </div>
    <div class="secondary-text">

    </div>
    Loading.....
  </div>
</div>
</ion-app>
```

I had used the above in few of my projects, and one specific issue I noticed is that the *CSS styles work only if written in index.html* itself.